# bluemix deploy the app with the command line interface

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have installed the IBM® Bluemix® and Cloud Foundry command line interfaces.

However, when I try to use the Bluemix command in bash, it states that the command is not found.

Is there any thing to do before using the command?

Comment: Try the `cf` command instead (such as `cf login`). The `bluemix` command is literally just a synonym for the `cf` command. You also want to make sure the bluemix binary you installed is available in your PATH variable, else it won't be accessible.

Comment: As a safety measure, the current directory is not part of the default path. If you're in the same folder, you have to refer to binaries with `./filename` if you want to run them, e.g. `./cf push`.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the [Bluemix CLI](http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html) and you get a "command not found" when you type the command `bluemix`, that would indicate that you are encountering path issues.

Potential steps to resolve this issue are:

1. Closing and re-opening your terminal
2. Reinstalling the plugin
3. Finding where you installed the plugin and launching the binary from the terminal (and optionally creating an alias)

> **Note:** The Bluemix CLI command line interface is not supported by Cygwin. Use the Bluemix CLI in a command line window other than the Cygwin command line window.

---

After getting the CLI installed, you will need to target the correct endpoint using `bx api` or `cf api`.

Finally you will need to login using `bx login` or `cf login`.

Comment: Hi @user1675407, are you still encountering this issue?